# Difference in initialization of Threads .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading

What's the difference between following initializations of the threads and when I should use them?

```
Printer printer = new Printer();
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(printer.Print0));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(printer.Print0);
Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => printer.Print0());
```

Comment: The same constructor is used in all cases. The delegate called by the `Thread(ThreadStart)` constructor is specified in different ways though, 1) explicitly, 2) as a method group and 3) as a lambda which calls `Print0`.

Comment: Thanks. And is there any advantage to use the explicit call and the lambda expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `System.Threading.Thread` has [the constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-threading-thread-ctor(system-threading-threadstart)) :

```cs
public class Thread
{
    public Thread (System.Threading.ThreadStart start);
}
```

Why `System.Threading.ThreadStart start` is a [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadstart) :

```cs
public delegate void ThreadStart();
```

The syntax to instantiate a delegate is :

```cs
ThreadStart myDelegate = new ThreadStart(printer.Print0);

// C#2 add this sugar syntax, but it's same instruction that below
ThreadStart myDelegate = printer.Print0;
```

Then this syntax are equivalent :

```cs
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(printer.Print0));
Thread thread2 = new Thread(printer.Print0);
```

Just the second use the sugar syntax add in C#2.

---

In C#3, [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/delegates-lambdas) is add in the language with a new way to declare a delegate :

```cs
ThreadStart myDelegate = () => { printer.Print0 };
```

It's like :

```cs
public class MyLambda
{
    public Printer printer;

    void Run()
    {
        printer.Print0();
    }
}

ThreadStart myDelegate = new MyLambda() { printer = printer }.Run;
```

Not exactly like the first example, because technically it call a intermediate method. But the only perceptive difference is the call stack... I consider this syntax similar.

---

To your question from your comment :

> Is there any advantage to use the explicit call and the lambda expression?

No, it's just different syntax. You can choose the one you prefer whitout other consideration.

Comment: If you want do multi-threading in dotnet, consider to use [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl).

Comment: Thanks for great explanation :) Now it it clear to me.

Comment: Of course, I use Task Library. I just wanted to know what is behind it.